# How to receive multiple processes from a main process

Tags: erlang

I am having a main process that will receive results from three processes. Each spawned process will return a tuple like `{Pid,R}`. My goal is to get the results (3) from three processes and save them in a tuple like `{R1,R2,R3}`. I don't know how to save the results inside the tuple like that. Here is how to get the results. Can someone help me return the tuple from the main process? Thank you.

```
mainprocess(N)->
    receive
        {Pid1,R1}->
            R1,
            loop();
        {Pid2,R2}->
            R2,
            loop();
        {Pid3,R3}->
            R3,
            loop()
    end.
```

Comment: Your indentation is horribly broken. Don't mix spaces and tabs.

Comment: What do you mean by, "Each spawning process will return a tuple…"? Are you aware that they have to send them as messages to the receiving process, not return them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many information missing in your question, so I made some assumptions:

you don't mind about the order of information,

the mainprocess function is there only to collect the answers from 3 other ones,

the responsibility to spawn the processes and to maintain a long living process is out of the scope of this question

with these assumptions you can simply collect the answers in the mainprocess function in 3 different variables and build the tuple at the end:

```
main_process_init(N) -> 
%% I don't know what is the usage of N in your example I just forward it to the loop
    R1 = get_answer(),
    R2 = get_answer(),
    R3 = get_answer(),
    main_process_loop(N,{R1,R2,R3}). 
    %% I suppose that when you got the answers you can enter in the main process loop

%% each message is received in a separate receive bloc
get_answer() ->
    receive
        {_,R} -> R   %% you never use the information Pid, so don't care about its value
    end.
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to wait for each process in a separate receive, like this

```
main() ->
    Pid1 = spawn(?MODULE, worker, [self(), 1]),
    Pid2 = spawn(?MODULE, worker, [self(), 2]),
    Pid3 = spawn(?MODULE, worker, [self(), 3]),
    R1 = receive
             {Pid1, N} ->
                 N
         end,
    R2 = receive
             {Pid2, N2} ->
                 N2
         end,
    R3 = receive
             {Pid3, N3} ->
                 N3
         end,
    {R1,R2,R3}.
```

Here you start by waiting for the result from the first process. Once that is received it moves on and waits for the result of the second process, and then the same thing for the third result.

No need to recursively call `main` and assembling the result tuple.

Comment: Thank you. that solved my problem. I just started learning Erlang for two weeks, so there are a lot of things I need to learn. I didnot know that we can cast the receive statement to a variable. Now I see. ty.